# How can I view Tensor as an image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I learned some data with tensorflow.

For the test, I saw the shape of the final result.

It was tensor of (1, 80, 80, 1).

I use matplotlib or PIL to do this,

I wanted to see the image after changing to a pie array.

But I could not change the tensor to numpy.

I could not do anything because of the session even if I used eval ().

There is no way to convert tensor to numpy.

Can I see the tensor as an image?

```
(mytensor1) # mytensor

arr = np.ndarray(mytensor1)
arr_ = np.squeeze(arr)
plt.imshow(arr_)
plt.show()
```

but there is error message:
TypeError: expected sequence object with len >= 0 or a single integer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use squeeze function from numpy. 
For example

```
arr = np.ndarray((1,80,80,1))#This is your tensor
arr_ = np.squeeze(arr) # you can give axis attribute if you wanna squeeze in specific dimension
plt.imshow(arr_)
plt.show()
```

Now, you can easily display this image (e.g. above code, assuming you are using `matplotlib.pyplot as plt`).

Comment: can you show the whole error log? also, what's your datatype for mytensor1?

Comment: error is "TypeError: expected sequence object with len >= 0 or a single integer"     datatype is float32

Comment: @talos1904 excuse me , what is the result will represent ? if i got image with colored pixels , Did that meaning thing ?

Answer (score 13):

For people using PyTorch, the simplest way that I know is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(my_tensor.numpy()[0], cmap='gray')
```

That should do it

Comment: That's a nice quick way for grayscale (although you might have to add `.cpu()` before `.numpy()`). But for displaying the image in true colors you could do: `plt.imshow(np.transpose(my_tensor.cpu().numpy(), (1,2,0)))`. I got this from this [Kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/jaeboklee/pytorch-cat-vs-dog/output).

Comment: RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead. I receive this error , what could be the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Torch is in shape of channel,height,width need to convert it into height,width, channel so permute.

```
plt.imshow(white_torch.permute(1, 2, 0))
```

Or directly if you want

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision.io import read_image
import torchvision.transforms as T

!wget 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553284965-83fd3e82fa5a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8NHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80'  -O white_horse.jpg

white_torch = torchvision.io.read_image('white_horse.jpg')

T.ToPILImage()(white_torch)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your image has only one channel (ie: black and white), you can also use`plt.matshow`:

```
image = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1,80,80,1))
image = image.reshape(80,80)
plt.matshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the tensor to np.array and reshape it as shown below and change it to 3 channel Image

```
def tensorToImageConversion(Tensor):
    # if it doesn't work remove *255 and try it 
    Tensor = Tensor*255
    Tensor = np.array(Tensor, dtype=np.uint8)
    if np.ndim(Tensor)>3:
        assert Tensor.shape[0] == 1
        Tensor = Tensor[0]
    return PIL.Image.fromarray(Tensor)
```